# why does webdriver launches chrome in maximized state

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

why does webdriver launches chrome in maximized state ? even though I have not set it for maximize.

I want to open it in a restored way.My need is to open it in the state it was left by my previous instance of webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(420,600);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

You can try this. I found it from: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: You are hard coding the size. My need is to open it in the state it was left by my previous instance of webdriver.

Comment: Try to get the size of the window in the previous instance, store it, then set it to that later. driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth()

Comment: I tried this, still it opens in a default way the webdriver opens it first time. Infact I debugged it and found that once widow is closed, driver instance is  still there, we get exception when trying to find the window.getSize(). So I could not cache the dimension.